# What is a proper word to describe someone who deeply regrets something?

Tags: word-choice, word-request, adjectives

What kind of adjective would you use to describe someone who, has done something terrible but wishes to be forgiven? *Apologetic* feels like it doesn't carry enough weight, and doesn't guarantee regret.

Possibly something to describe someone feeling *Sorrow* over actions, choices or events.

Comment: The word you are looking for is *remorseful.*

Comment: Also related: *repentance*. (But if you're looking for an adjective, I'd say *regretful* is just fine.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> [Penitent](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/penitent)

or

> [Repentant](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/repentant).

Either expresses a deep remorse for something you have done wrong.  Be aware that both are frequently used in a *religious* context, so there can be a slightly [pious](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/pious) nuance.

Examples:

> The judge asked if the defendant truly repented his crime.
>
> She stood before the crowd, unrepentant of what she had done.
>
> [Only the penitant man will pass](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NkGTyndJC1w)